# "Kernel header files not in any of expected locations" when compiling ixgbe driver

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I want to compile the Intel ixgbe driver, but it appears such mistakes which was depicted in the picture below:

[image]

I have installed development tools,but the error still appears:

[image]

Comment: Apart from that: have you tried to install the suggested package? The "Development Tools" pattern contains development tools, I would assume, not necessarily that header package.

Comment: "Development Tools" indicates Fedora, CentOS : # `yum install kernel-devel` → → that's the required kernel headers for `/usr/src/* `

Comment: Why do you need that? All major distros have a kernels with up to date drivers.

Comment: the command yum install kernel-devel is executed,but the misstake is still appears

Answer (score 4):

I found that, in my case, I just had to reboot for the development tools to fully install. After the reboot, the make command worked fine.

Comment: This was the correct answer. The kernel headers are not from whatever reason visible after installing through yum. Thanks.

Comment: In my case I had to do both 'yum install kernel-devel' and 'yum install kernel'. A reboot was required.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (Fedora 34)

```
sudo dnf groupinstall "Development Tools" "Development Libraries"
```

and reboot right after.

Reference: https://www.osradar.com/install-development-build-tools-fedora/